# jquery: Disable/Enable button not working after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a form with n multiple choice questions implemented as radio buttons (using `jquery-ui`). I would like to ensure that all the questions have been answered before allowing the user to submit the form. I am running into two issues while performing this validation:

- On initial load, the submit button does not respond to clicks or mouseovers until all questions have a response selected as desired. However, it still appears to be clickable (I would like this to be faded out)

[image]

- If the reset button is pressed, the submit button is faded out (as desired) but I am unable to re-enable the submit button once the form has been completed.

[image]

This is my first time using javascipt/jquery. What is going wrong? How do I achieve the desired functionality across both cases?

---

Here is the pertinent javascript portion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.button' ).button ();
    $( '.radio-set' ).buttonset ();
    $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );

    var progress = 0;
    var total_fields = $('.response').length

    /* Track Progress function*/
    $('input[type="radio"]').click( function(){        
      progress = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length
      $(".progressbar").progressbar( {value: ( progress / total_fields ) * 100} )
      console.log(progress, total_fields)
      if( progress == total_fields ){
        console.log( "Hello from inside the conditional" )
        $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
      } 
    });

    $( 'input[type="reset"]' ).click( function(){
      progress = 0
      $( ".progressbar" ).progressbar( {value: 0} )
      $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
    });
});
```

Example of one of the questions within the form (with bacon filler text):

```
        <div class="model_feature">
          <span class="feature_name" title="M1">M1</span>
          <span class="response radio-set">
            <label for="M1-1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1" id="M1-1" value="1"  class="feature-input" autocomplete="off" />
            <label for="M1-0">0</label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1" id="M1-0" value="0"  class="feature-input" autocomplete="off" />
            <label for="M1-Unk">Unknown</label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1" id="M1-Unk" value="Unknown"  class="feature-input" autocomplete="off" />
          </span <!-- close response -->
          <span class="feature_description">Chicken spare ribs capicola beef brisket hamburger. Kielbasa filet mignon tail ribeye ball tip ground round.</span>
        </div> <!-- close model_feature -->
```

Input and Reset buttons for completeness:

```
        <input type="reset" class="button" id="reset-button" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit-button" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you turn you button to a jQuery UI Button, you'd better use the jQuery UI methods of the Button plugin to enable/disbale your button, instead of the changing directly the DOMElement attribute `disabled`.

1. For the initial state, you initialize your Button and then only change the `disabled` attribute, so the change is taken into account by the Button plugin.

   ```
   // either disable first the button then initialize
   $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
   $( '.button' ).button ();
   ```

   or

   ```
   // set the Button's option
   $( '.button' ).button ();
   $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).button('option', 'disabled', true);
   ```
2. For the second problem, use the Button's option setter to re-enable your button:

   ```
   $( 'input[type="submit"]' ).button('option', 'disabled', false);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by waiting for a while before adding the `disabled` attribute. Example,

```
var btn = $("button").first();
$(btn).button("loading");
$(btn).button("reset");
setTimeout(function () {
    $(btn).prop("disabled", true);
}, 0);
```

A same so question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968611/jquery-attr-not-working-on-bootstrap-button-after-reset) and a gihub issue [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6242).