# jQuery attr() not working on Bootstrap button after reset

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple code that doesn't work and I don't understand what I'm missing.

#### External resources

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### HTML

```
<p>
    <button id="btn-id" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" data-loading-text="loading stuff...">Click Me</button>
</p>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-id").button();

    $("#btn-id").click(function () {
        //$("#btn-id").attr("disabled",true);
        $(this).button('loading');

        setTimeout(function () {
            //this desn't work. The button resets but it doesn't get disabled afterwards
            $("#btn-id").button('reset').attr("disabled", true);

            //the bellow line works as expected
            //$("#btn-id").button('reset').addClass("btn-success");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

It seems that after `button('reset')`, I can `addClass('someclass')` but I can't disable the button anymore.

Why is this not working and how can I fix it?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexsutu/F8PS6/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: Disable/Enable button not working after reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707229/jquery-disable-enable-button-not-working-after-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way, but you can use a workaround

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-id").button();

    $("#btn-id").click(function () {
        $(this).button('loading');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#btn-id").addClass('btn-success').data('loading-text', 'OK').button('loading')
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/F8PS6/3/)

Comment: that is a great idea and it works. Just waiting for couple more thoughts. If not I will mark this as the right answer.

Comment: @AlexSutu actually you can just leave it in the loading state, you don't need that `.button('loading')` at the end of my line. I just saw that. the loading state is already the disabled state so it's not a big problem

Comment: you're right. The workaround was so simple yet I lost couple of hours on this. Not sure though why you can't actually re-add the disabled attribute after reset.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the setTimeout used in the Button.prototype.setState() method:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-button.js#L46

Here is a workaround for this:

```
var $btn = $('.btn-save');
$btn.button('reset');
setTimetout(function() {
    $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Disables the button correctly.
}, 0);
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/BKXVA/)

---

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6242
Credit goes to: https://github.com/f0t0n

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a class 'disabled' on top of the disabled attribute (it works the same way in bootstrap 3) :

```
$("#btn-id").addClass('btn-success').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled').html('OK');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Urc95/)

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution is this :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $btn = $("#btn-id").button();

    $btn.click(function () {
        $(this).data('loading-text', 'Loading wait...');
        $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
            $(this).button('reset');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });

    // You can callback after completion, essential for those who need to add classes
    $('#reset-button').click(function () {
        $btn.button('reset');
        $btn.dequeue().delay(100).queue(function(){
            console.log('Loading completed');
            // This button
            $(this).addClass('loading-completed');

            // And very important for who callback function, examples:
            /*
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(this);
            }
            */
        });// enable button
    });

});//ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

#### Updated code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-id").button();
    
    $("#btn-id").click(function () {
        $("#btn-id").prop("disabled",true);
        $(this).button('loading');
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            //this desn't work. The button resets but it doesn't get disabled afterwards
            $("#btn-id").button('reset').prop("disabled", true);
            
            //the bellow line works as expected
            //$("#btn-id").button('reset').addClass("btn-success");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FTX5H/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Same result using prop instead of attr.

Comment: the fiddle you provided still doesn't disable the button after reset. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The good solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592930/418599) unfortunately does not work for me, so I have rewritten it as follow:

```
function( element, status ) {        
    if ( status ) {
        element.removeClass( 'bs-disabled' );
    } else {
        element.addClass( 'bs-disabled' );
    }

    function setStatus() {
        if ( status ) {
            element.removeProp( 'disabled' );
        } else {
            element.prop( 'disabled', true );
        }
    };

    setTimeout( setStatus, 500 );
}
```

where the style is:

```
.btn.bs-disabled {
    border: black 1px dotted;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```